# parse string hh:mm:ss to timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey how to convert string in timestamp

I recovered the text of time and I convert it in date

when I converted to timestamp the value is negative

```js
var timenow=$("#time").text();
var res = timenow.split(":");
var d80 = new Date();
var curr_date = d80.getDate();
var curr_month = d80.getMonth();

var curr_year = d80.getFullYear();
var date1 = new Date(curr_date, curr_month, curr_year, res[0], res[1],res[2]);

console.log(date1);

const timestamp = date1 / 1000;
console.log(timestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">
00:50:30
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the date constructor in right way

`new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);`

More information: [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
var timenow=$("#time").text();
var res = timenow.split(":");
var d80 = new Date();
var curr_date = d80.getDate();
var curr_month = d80.getMonth();


var curr_year = d80.getFullYear();


var date1 = new Date(curr_year,curr_month, curr_date,res[0], res[1], res[2]);

console.log(date1); //"2019-10-26T01:20:00.000Z"


const timestamp = date1.getTime();// to get timestamp
console.log(timestamp);

let date2 = new Date(timestamp);
console.log(date2); //"2019-10-26T01:20:00.000Z"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">
00:50:30
</div>
```

Comment: but when i converted timestamp in date i did not find the same result

Comment: You should get timestamp by using `date1.getTime()` not dividing it by 1000

Comment: just I have last questions please
how compare difference between 00:50:30 and anthoer variable for exemple 01:20:50

Comment: If you want to compare time then you can't just compare 01:20:50 and 00:50:30 cause they are strings if you compare them they will get lexicographically compared giving the wrong answer maybe it will work but that is not the correct way to compare time. You have to convert them into `date` objects like I did date1 and date2 then you can compare them using comparison operators. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: There's a mistake
the correct is
 var date1 = new Date(curr_year,curr_month, curr_date,res[0], res[1], res[2]);

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Date's constructor wrong. First parameter is the year:

```
var date1 = new Date(curr_year, curr_month, curr_date, res[0], res[1],res[2]);
```

Also, I think your code can be improved:

```
const [hours, minutes, seconds] = $("#time").text().split(":");

let currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds)

const timestamp = currentDate.getTime();
console.log(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, a timestamp is the amount of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 (1 January 1970 is also known as Unix epoch time)

In your sample code `date1` is 1931-04-11. Some 39 years before the epoch! Hence the negative value.

You need to use the correct format when constructing `date1`:

```
var date1 = new Date(curr_year, curr_month, curr_date, res[0], res[1],res[2]);
```

EG:

```js
var timenow=$("#time").text();
var res = timenow.split(":");
var d80 = new Date();
var curr_date = d80.getDate();
var curr_month = d80.getMonth();

var curr_year = d80.getFullYear();
//var date1 = new Date(curr_date, curr_month, curr_year, res[0], res[1],res[2]);

var date1 = new Date(curr_year, curr_month, curr_date, res[0], res[1],res[2]);
console.log(date1);

const timestamp = date1 / 1000;
console.log(timestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">
00:50:30
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but when i converted timestamp in date i did not find the same result